# In C#, String .Replace wont replace danish chars

Tags: c#, .net, string, str-replace

so I have string containing a Danish char (æ), say:

`string textString = "tæst";
 string newString = "";`

for some reason this

```
newString = textString .Replace("æ", "e");
```

Is not replacing correctly, it's resulting `newString = "tæst"` when it's supposed to be `newString = "test"`.

However, **NOT ALWAYS**!

I have tested on multiple servers, on some this is returned correctly as `"test"` on others this is `"tæst"`.

I am thinking in terms of, maybe the string is not recognized as a utf8 string, and should maybe be forced to be recognized as a utf8. Just a guess, do you have an idea/guess?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide reproducible code. `string new = "";` is not a valid C# code.

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it.

Comment: Are you saying that the _same_ `.exe` produces different results on different servers?

Comment: RBM, exactly! Very strange, suggestions?

Comment: simple. there is more than one `ӕ` character and few ways to represent it  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D3%95. `ӕ` vs `æ`

Comment: What is the difference between the servers? .NET version, globalization, setting for non-unicode etc.?

Comment: @Slai but he says it's the _same_ `.exe` producing` different results; the `.exe` has the `ӕ` hardcoded (or at least that's my understanding of the problem)

Comment: ok, this is crazy. Listen to what I did. I deleted the 'æ' char, copied a random one from the wiki article (the first on top). And now it works all accross. WTF????? What does this tell you?

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Comment: If copying the character from the wiki fixed it then it suggests Slai was right. Downvotes are because SO likes questions that can be directly replicated and fixed, guessing games based on foreign OS languages and encodings are not generally well received.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the explanation Equalsk. Now I will know how to formulate my questions in the future :)

Comment: Look at the int values of both characters: the one you originally had and the one from the wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Unicode characters have multiple versions that can look very alike. For example: [1１①⑴](http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=1)

```
var s = "æӕ".Replace("æ", "ae"); // s = "aeæ"
var v = "æӕ".Select(c => (int)c).ToArray(); // { 230, 1237 }
```

I consider it a good practice to expect the unexpected (especially when it comes to user input)

```
var s = "æӕ";
var a = s.ToCharArray(); // or use StringBuilder for non 1 to 1 character replacements

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    if (a[i] > 127)
        switch (a[i]) {
            case 'æ': case 'ӕ': 
                a[i] = 'e'; break;
            default: 
                Debug.Print("Unexpected character " + a[i]);
        }

s = new string(a);
```

Here are some unrelated [Falsehoods Programmers Believe](https://www.google.com/search?q=Falsehoods+Programmers+Believe)

Answer (score -1):

***Edit***. Yep, didn't read the question properly. :(

Rbm is correct above. new isn't a valid name. This code works.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "tæst";
        string s = string.Empty;

        s = text.Replace("æ", "e");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, same problem as before. On some servers - s = "tæst" - , on others - s = "test".